# Error when inserting large amount of rows to a table with rowversion/timestamp column (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to insert large amount of rows with an INSERT INTO / SELECT statement to a table that has a rowversion/timestamp column.

The INSERT statement always returns an error:

> An internal error happened while generating a new DBTS for database.
>   Please retry the operation.

Is there any size limit when inserting the data in a single transaction to the table with rowversion/timestamp column?

I've read all the MSDN pages related and it seems that this should work. It seems very strange, like a bug. I've tried the same on 3 different servers (all VMware virtualized) using the following SQL Server versions (all Enterprise x64):

- 13.0.4411.0
- 13.0.4001.0
- 13.0.2164.0

This is the script to reproduce the error:

```
USE Db1
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[TESTTABLE]
GO

-- insert 400 million dummy records 
SELECT 
    TOP 400000000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number 
INTO 
    [dbo].[TESTTABLE]
FROM 
    sys.columns s1       
CROSS JOIN 
    sys.columns s2 
CROSS JOIN 
    sys.columns s3 


USE Db2
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[TESTTABLE]
GO

-- create table with a timestamp/rowversion column
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTTABLE](
    [StageTimestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SomeNumber] [int] NOT NULL
)

GO

-- insert 400 million records into the table
INSERT INTO
    [dbo].[TESTTABLE] WITH (TABLOCK) (SomeNumber)
SELECT
    Number
FROM
    [db1].[dbo].[TESTTABLE]
GO
```

Comment: your db1 testtable conatins 1 column, your db2 testtable contains two fields. maybe you need to specify a field list in your insert?

Comment: The column list is specified at INSERT ("SomeNumber" column). The other column "StageTimestamp" should be automatically populated (that's the point of it) - that's why it's not specified in the column list.

Comment: Looks like there could be an issue with DBTS in 2016. Found this on microsoft connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3118341/an-internal-error-happened-while-generating-a-new-dbts-for-database-test-db-please-retry-the-operation

Comment: Seems so. 

I've just tested this on SQL Server 2014, installed as a separate instance on the same server and it works on SQL 2014. 

It's very strange, but indeed seems to be a bug in the database engine of  SQL 2016.

Comment: @saso I hope you submit this to microsoft connect. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback

Answer (score 0):

This is not a permanent fixed, but did some trial and error and came out with a workaround. The insert works fine when inserting a smaller block of records, tested with 10 million and 50 million block, the insert does not failed. The second part of the script has been updated to loop.

```
USE Db2
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[TESTTABLE]
GO

-- create table with a timestamp/rowversion column
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTTABLE](
    [StageTimestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SomeNumber] [int] NOT NULL
)

GO

DECLARE @rowcount INT = 1
DECLARE @LastNumber INT = 0
WHILE (@rowcount > 0)
BEGIN
    --insert 50 million blocks of records into the table
    INSERT INTO
        [dbo].[TESTTABLE] WITH (TABLOCK) (SomeNumber)
    SELECT TOP(50000000)
        Number
    FROM
        [db1].[dbo].[TESTTABLE]
    WHERE Number > @LastNumber

    --get insert rows, it will loop until no more rows is inserted
    SET @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

    --get the last number
    SELECT @LastNumber = MAX(SomeNumber) FROM [dbo].[TESTTABLE]
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here because it was the first result when looking up the error in german. I did a little more digging and found this blog post here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/an-internal-error-happened-while-generating-a-new-dbts-for/ba-p/334021

It explains what is happening in the background quite well to better understand the issue.

I fixed my problem by catching the error, setting task to sleep .5 seconds and then send the same command again.

I set a limit of 10 retries which it hasn't reached so far.